# Issue with postgres row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER BY) function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been using row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER BY) in a query, it's been working fine for a few days but now I'm getting the error:

ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 3145728 in memory context "TupleSort main".
SQL state: 53200

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Looks like the partitions you defined in the window are becoming too big.

Comment: `work_mem` is set so high that you are running out of memory. It is not necessarily the failing query that consumes all the memory. Try reducing `work_mem`. An alternative explanation is that your operating system is misconfigured. Please tell us how much RAM there is, how `max_connections`, `work_mem` and `shared_buffers` are set and what `sysctl -a | grep overcommit` shows (if you are using Linux).